# recursively match a column using regex

Tags: regex

I have a log file formatted as below:

```
<134> 1 2014 Jul 31 18:48:03 - - MYAPP - [blablabla aNumber 10.70.4.126 bablabla - anotherIP 56389 anotherPortNumber - anotherIP anotherPortNumber ]
```

The pattern within square brackets can repeat 2 or more times in a single line, so my log file might looks like:

```
2014 Jul 31 18:48:03 - - MYAPP - [blablabla aNumber 10.70.4.126 bablabla - anotherIP 56389 anotherPortNumber - anotherIP anotherPortNumber ]
2014 Jul 31 18:48:03 - - MYAPP - [blablabla aNumber 10.70.4.126 bablabla - anotherIP 56389 anotherPortNumber - anotherIP anotherPortNumber ][blablabla aNumber 10.70.4.127 bablabla - anotherIP 56390 anotherPortNumber - anotherIP anotherPortNumber ]
2014 Jul 31 18:48:03 - - MYAPP - [blablabla aNumber 10.70.4.126 bablabla - anotherIP 56389 anotherPortNumber - anotherIP anotherPortNumber ][blablabla aNumber 10.70.4.127 bablabla - anotherIP 56390 anotherPortNumber - anotherIP anotherPortNumber ][blablabla aNumber 10.70.4.128 bablabla - anotherIP 56391 anotherPortNumber - anotherIP anotherPortNumber ]
```

For each square brackets in line, I need to match the 1st IP number and the 1st Port number using a Regex.

My question: is there any RegEx representation that can recursively extract columns from a repeated pattern (in this case columns would be 3 and 7 having white space as a separator) ?

I appreciate beforehand any suggestion

Comment: What have you tried? This doesn't seem to require particularly complex knowledge of regex. Also, it would be extremely helpful to have exact data when dealing with regex issues, rather than "aNumber" and "anotherIP".

Comment: I do not see what is recursive, you can simply make a repeated pattern.

Comment: maybe its a good idea to have a look on [see awk command](http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/gawk/gawk_3.html) , specially if you just want to extract by column number , try this `cat logfile | awk '{print $3 $7}'` for matching ip there is a plenty of good example on the web

Answer (score 1):

here is a regex to match all the ip and ports

**Regex**

```
((?:\d+\.){3}\d+)(?:.*?)(\d+)
```

**Test String**

```
2014 Jul 31 18:48:03 - - MYAPP - [blablabla aNumber 10.70.4.126 bablabla - anotherIP 56389 anotherPortNumber - anotherIP anotherPortNumber ]
2014 Jul 31 18:48:03 - - MYAPP - [blablabla aNumber 10.70.4.126 bablabla - anotherIP 56389 anotherPortNumber - anotherIP anotherPortNumber ][blablabla aNumber 10.70.4.127 bablabla - anotherIP 56390 anotherPortNumber - anotherIP anotherPortNumber ]
2014 Jul 31 18:48:03 - - MYAPP - [blablabla aNumber 10.70.4.126 bablabla - anotherIP 56389 anotherPortNumber - anotherIP anotherPortNumber ][blablabla aNumber 10.70.4.127 bablabla - anotherIP 56390 anotherPortNumber - anotherIP anotherPortNumber ][blablabla aNumber 10.70.4.128 bablabla - anotherIP 56391 anotherPortNumber - anotherIP anotherPortNumber ]
```

**Result**

MATCH 1

1. [52-63] `10.70.4.126`
2. [85-90] `56389`

MATCH 2

1. [193-204]   `10.70.4.126`
2. [226-231]   `56389`

MATCH 3

1. [300-311]   `10.70.4.127`
2. [333-338]   `56390`

MATCH 4

1. [441-452]   `10.70.4.126`
2. [474-479]   `56389`

MATCH 5

1. [548-559]   `10.70.4.127`
2. [581-586]   `56390`

MATCH 6

1. [655-666]   `10.70.4.128`
2. [688-693]   `56391`

try [demo here](http://regex101.com/r/nC3kJ6/1)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not fully sure if I understood what you need but here I post this answer to extract the ip and port. Using this regex:

```
\[.*?([\d\.]+).*?\-.*?(\d+).*?\]
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/hM3xP2/1)**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
/(\[([^ ]+ ){2}([^ ])+ ([^ ]+ ){3}([^ ]+ )[^\]]+\])+/
```